# Angular and SEO, ngClick vs href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

I couldn't find the answer to this one so im gonna hope for someone to respond me.
In my Rails + Angular app i have an anchor that look like this in a paginator.

```
<a href='/list?page_param=2' ng-click='loadPage(2)'>2</a>
```

Where `loadPage(2)` prevents the default behaviour.

My question is directed towards SEO, the page looks fine an the result of the pagination is embedded via AJAX, but what will SEO index? or what is the SEO hightest priority? Will it fetch the url in the `href` or will it execute the `js` function in the `ng-click` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search engines typically do not execute the javascript embedded on the page. In your case, as long as the anchor tag has a valid anchor link, that is what will be indexed by the search engine. More details [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) (The current practice section) and [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html)

Comment: Those links have bee deprecated.